# Extract column of data frame based on logical vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to extract the columns of a data frame based on logical vector. My data frame `df` is

```
structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4), 
    Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 
    1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
    0.2, 0.2, 0.4), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Sepal.Length", 
"Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

And I have a logical vector say `x <- c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)` . How to extract the columns of logical `TRUE`

Comment: Please read an introductory R tutorial. This _really_ basic stuff. Googling your title (with an "R" in addition) would have given you the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can just use `[` to extract the columns as the `x` is a logical vector and it will only select the columns corresponding to TRUE values in 'x'.

```
df[x]
```

Also, by the row, column indexing, it may be useful to specify the `,` to separate the row and column index, i.e. `df[,x]`.  If we don't use the `,`, by default, the column index is selected.  When we use the `,`, and if there is only a single `TRUE` value in 'x', the `data.frame` will be converted to `vector` as by default we have `drop=TRUE` with `[`.  Then, we may need to specify `df[,x, drop=FALSE]`.